# .map() is mapping the wrong value to my header tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I'm creating an app that allows staff members to book out equipment from our store. When we click the 'Book Out' button I'm using reactstrap to open a modal so the employee can add further info. When the modal opens I want the items name in the modal heading but for some reason when i use `.map()` it gives all the modals the same heading but `.map()` is working for everything else?

To save you time the error occurs with only this section of code:

```
<ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>
  {item.name}
</ModalHeader>
```

I'm not sure what the problem is and would love any help I can get!

```
{events.map(item => {
  if (item.isBooked === true) {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-4 item p-2">
        <img className="item-img-booked" src={item.img} alt="" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <h6 className="text-center">{item.name}</h6>
        <button className="btn btn-success btn-sm m-1">Return</button>
      </div>
    );
  } else
    return (
      <div className="col-md-4 item p-2">
        <img className="item-img" src={item.img} alt="" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <h6 className="text-center">{item.name}</h6>
        <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>
          Book Out
        </Button>
        <div>
          <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
            <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>
              {item.name}
            </ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
              elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
              dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
              nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
              ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
              reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
              fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
              non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
              anim id est laborum.
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
              <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>
                Confrim
              </Button>
              {" "}
              <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>
                Cancel
              </Button>
            </ModalFooter>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
)}
```

Comment: `.map()` uses data from the array, if the heading is wrong then maybe the name of header in array is wrong.

Comment: @JuniusL. Unfortunately thats not it. The name is correct in the array. You can see I use {item.name} on two occasions in the same mapping. One time it works as expected and the other it uses the name of the last item in the array

Comment: please create a simple working project with your issue here https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @JuniusL. Here is the link: https://react-us21xi.stackblitz.io/events I couldn't get reactstrap to work though...

Comment: I want to see the code, where is the code?

Comment: @JuniusL. ahh, my bad. Here is the right link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-us21xi?file=index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a modal for each item, move the modal outside of the `.map()` and save your items in the state. Pass the index of each item to `toggle` function and use that index to get the name of the item, from events in state like `this.state.events[index]`. Your modal will pull the name from state.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "reactstrap";

export class EventsAll extends Component {
  state = {
    modal: false,
    index: -1,
    events: [],
    name: ""
  };

  toggle = index => {
    const ind = typeof index !== "number" ? -1 : index;

    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        modal: !prevState.modal,
        index: ind
      }),
      () => {
        this.populateModalData();
      }
    );
  };

  populateModalData = () => {
    if (this.state.index < 0 || typeof this.state.index !== "number") {
      return;
    }

    const item = this.state.events[this.state.index];

    this.setState({
      name: item.name
    });
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const { events } = this.props.events;

    this.setState({
      events: events
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          {this.state.events.map((item, index) => {
            if (item.isBooked === true) {
              return (
                <div className="col-md-4 item p-2">
                  <img className="item-img-booked" src={item.img} alt="" />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <h6 className="text-center">{item.name}</h6>
                  <button className="btn btn-success btn-sm m-1">Return</button>
                </div>
              );
            } else
              return (
                <div className="col-md-4 item p-2">
                  <img className="item-img" src={item.img} alt="" />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <h6 className="text-center">{item.name}</h6>
                  <Button
                    val={index}
                    color="danger"
                    onClick={() => this.toggle(index)}
                  >
                    Book Out
                  </Button>
                  <div />
                </div>
              );
          })}
        </div>

        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>{this.state.name}</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
            aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
            pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
            culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>
              Confrim
            </Button>{" "}
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EventsAll;
```

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r92chy)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your toggling function toggles all the modals all together, so where ever you click, only last modal is visible to you.

Try to utilize an array to toggle your modal visibility state.

Comment: You're 100% right. When I removed the reactstrap cdn and clicked the button it displayed all the modals. But how would I use an array to fix that problem? I'm sorry if I come across as noobish, I'm still a very junior dev.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your question completely but from the title I guess that your problem is that you don't use a `key` attribute for your components and when the `item.isBooked` changes, your components don't change as well.

So, try this:
Change `events.map(item => {` to `events.map((item, index) => {` in order to generate a unique key every time `map` renders an item from `events`.
And for your `div`s inside return functions, do this:
`<div className="col-md-4 item p-2" key={index}>`
`<div className="col-md-4 item p-2" key={index}>`

Comment: So the problem is that the toggle function opens a modal for each object in my array. So it is actually mapping correctly but because it is creating a modal for each item, I can only see the modal for the last item in the array because it covers the rest. Now I'm trying to find a way for my toggle function to only open a single modal.

Comment: 'keys' are the way React knows when to rerender a element. Passing an index is almost always wrong. eg: you pass an array: it renders, then you sort the array, index of element won't change (first element will always be 0) and so not rerender.

Comment: @J.Hansen exactly, but as Pierre mentioned using map index is not that wise, but the reason that I told you to use it, is that I didn't see your code and I don't know any other unique data to use as a key.